# UNABLE TO IMPORT USING TRADITIONAL BACKUP IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

Am using 11.2.0.1 oracle version

while importing using traditional backup facing below error.

> IMP-00060: Warning: Skipping table "SCHEMA"."TABLE" because object type "MDSYS"."SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY"  does not exist or has different identifier

Am using below command

```
imp UNAME/PWD file=DUMP.dmp log=LOG.log fromuser=OLD touser=NEW buffer=24867596 grants=n statistics=none
```

Comment: Apparently Oracle Spatial was not installed in your your target database. But Oracle Spatial is only available as an [additional cost option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/editions.htm#DBLIC2152) when you have licensed the Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Oracle Standard Edition and not Oracle Enterprise Edition database.

1. Get access to Oracle EE
2. Unlock MDSYS user that is locked by default